# CesiumJS callback property for toggling visibility of an entity label based on mouse position

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cesiumjs

I have the following code for adding entities on a cesium canvas in the form of point graphics using latitude, longitude pairs.

```js
    for (const entity of this.someArrayOfCoordinates) {
      this.cesiumViewer.entities.add(new Cesium.Entity({
        position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(entity.lat, entity.lng),
        id: entity.id,
        point: new Cesium.PointGraphics({
          pixelSize: 15,
          color: entity.status === 'operational' ? Cesium.Color.GREEN :
                                                   Cesium.Color.RED,
        }),
        // onhover update this entity to have a label, and on outside of a
        // hover, update it to not have a visible label
        label: new Cesium.LabelGraphics({
          text: 'some label text',
          show: new Cesium.ConstantProperty(false)
        }),
      }));
    }
```

I use the following eventhandler for detecting if a mouse movement event is over an enitity or not.

```js
    const scene = this.cesiumViewer.scene;
    const handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(scene.canvas);
    handler.setInputAction((movement) => {
      const pickedObject = scene.pick(movement.endPosition);
      let currentEntity: Cesium.Entity|null = null;

      if (Cesium.defined(pickedObject) &&
          pickedObject.id instanceof Cesium.Entity) {
        currentEntity = pickedObject.id;  // DO NOT SUBMIT
        if (currentEntity) {
          console.log(1, currentEntity.label);
          currentEntity.label.show = new Cesium.ConstantProperty(true);
             //new Cesium.CallbackProperty((time, result) => {
             //return scene.pick(movement.endPosition) === pickedObject;
             }, false);
        }
      } else {
        console.log(3);
        if (currentEntity) {
          currentEntity.label.show = new Cesium.ConstantProperty(false);
          currentEntity = null;         
        }
      }
    }, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.MOUSE_MOVE);
```

Now, the label visibility does toggle once but gets stuck afterwards. Based on some reading online, I believe this is not the best way (if not incorrect) to achieve this. Readings suggested the use of Cesium.CallBackProperty() to get this done. I am unable to get the code for that to work. The commented code is a rudimentary attempt at that.

I would be grateful if someone could point out the correct way to achieve what I am trying to do or point out the mistake with my code.

Context: I am trying this in angular. Link to Cesium Sandcastle: [sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

PS: the cesium forums do not seem to be effective as they just marked my post as spam.

Update: I fixed it as follows: [sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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).

Now, the issue is that it works in cesium sandcastle but not in angular, the show property only toggles once.

Comment: can you share your code at Sandcastle: https://sandcastle.cesium.com/

Comment: @ZhefengJin, I've added the link as requested.